# Is there any automated way to create a collection and project in TFS 2018

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am curious to know is there any way to create a collection and project in TFS 2018 in an automated way.

Similar to how we can do in Bitbucket, using the API.

I tried most of the option provided in the internet. But no use.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and TFS 2018.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no automated way to **create** a team project collection, you have to [Create Team Project Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/dd236915(v=vs.120)) in TFS Administration Console. But you can use the **TFSConfig Collection** command to **attach**, **detach**, **delete**, or **clone** a team project collection. See [Collection command [TFSConfig]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ee349263%28v%3Dvs.120%29).

For team projects, you can create team projects from the command line or scripts using the [VSTS CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/overview?view=vsts-cli-latest&viewFallbackFrom=vsts). VSTS CLI works with VSTS and Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 2 and later. You could [install VSTS CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/install?view=vsts-cli-latest), read the [get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/get-started?view=vsts-cli-latest) article to begin using it, and refer to the [vsts project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/project?view=vsts-cli-latest) command.