# Possible to create Team Foundation Server Project programmatically?

Tags: tfs

I need to create Team Foundation Server projects, but the only way I can find to do it is manually through the website.

Is it possible to do programmatically via a CLI, programming language, or RESTful API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What **version** of TFS? Did you Google this first or otherwise do any independent research? This is very well-documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do programmatically via a CLI, programming language,
>   or RESTful API?

It's possible, you can do that using Rest API. `Azure Devops Server 2019` and `TFS 2018U2` both support creating project using Rest API.  [TFS2018U2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1), [Azure Devops Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0).

More details please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0).

Test with `TFS2018U2` in **PostMan**:

**Request URL:** `https://ServerName:8080/tfs/CollectionName/_apis/projects?api-version=4.1`

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "name": "CreateProjectTest",
  "description": "Just for Test",
  "capabilities": {
    "versioncontrol": {
      "sourceControlType": "Git"
    },
    "processTemplate": {
      "templateTypeId": "6b724908-ef14-45cf-84f8-768b5384da45"
    }
  }
}
```

If you get status `202 accepted`, then you can see the newly created project in website after some time (For me,10~25 seconds).

**Note:** The document states the format is `https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/projects?api-version=xxx`, but you need to use `http` instead of `https` when you Public URL starts with `http`:

[image]

**In addition:** Here's one [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50387408/10910450) to achieve what you want using CLI. And here's [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190267/10910450) that may give you some hint if you want to do that using C# code.

Hope all above helps :)

Comment: If a question is a duplicate of an existing question, **don't answer it**. Vote to close as a duplicate.